# What is coef() equivalent function in python

Tags: python, r

In `R` we have `coef()` that you can apply on a linear model and get all the different `coefficient` and `Intercept` value that built the linear model.

What is the equivalent code for this in `python`?

I need to interpret the `intercept` and `coefficients` from the `elastic net regression model` that i have done.

This will help me in forming the regression equation of the model.

Answer (score 1):

This depends what are you working with. Comment what are you working with and I'll edit my answer to help you.

For scikit-learn you should use the following:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

X = np.array([[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3]]) #Your x values, for a 2 variable model.
#y = 1 * x_0 + 2 * x_1 + 3 #This is the "true" model
y = np.dot(X, np.array([1, 2])) + 3 #Generating the true y-values
reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, y) #Fitting the model given your X and y values.
reg.coef_ #Prints an array of all regressor values (b1 and b2)
reg.intercept_  #Prints value for intercept/b0 
reg.predict(np.array([[3, 5]])) #Predicts an array of y-values with the fitted model given the inputs
```

From: [Scikit-learn linear_model_regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html)